# Automate Excel from .NET to prompt a user to select a single cell, and close workbook and return the cell reference immediately

Tags: .net, excel, vba, reference, automation

I have a (.NET Winforms) application which needs to open an Excel Workbook, prompt the user to select a cell from this workbook -- and upon single-clicking the cell, return immediately back to the calling (.NET Winforms application) a reference/pointer to the selected cell in the Excel workbook.

It is trivial to automate Excel in a manner which causes a user-selected Workbook to open, and to obtain a cell reference, however, I would like to be able to close the workbook immediately once a cell has been selected *without adding VBA to the Excel workbook*.

Is this possible in an elegant way?

Comment: Just [handle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabhan_berry/2008/02/12/excel-event-handling-in-c/) the [Workbook.SheetSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetselectionchange) event.

Comment: Just a thought: If you return a reference to an Excel object (Range), but closes the Excel workbook, I would highly assume that the reference will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks

It's not the most graceful solution but a combination of Comintern and FunThomas' comments is a good enough workaround for now.

Later, I'll probably just load the Excel worksheets into DataTables.

Cheers,

Mike